# how to poll a sftp server for new files using node js

Tags: node.js, express, sftp

Actually i need to poll a sftp server using node js whenever a new file is uploaded to the server in a specified location.

Is there any node package for poll a sftp server, now i can only read the files in the sftp server using node js. And currently looking to poll the server whenever a new file is uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ssh2-sftp-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2-sftp-client). Install it like this:

```
npm install ssh2-sftp-client
```

Following the documentation, for basic usage:

```
let Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
let sftp = new Client();

sftp.connect({
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: '8080',
  username: 'username',
  password: '******'
}).then(() => {
  return sftp.list('/pathname');
}).then(data => {
  console.log(data, 'the data info');
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err, 'catch error');
});
```

You can periodically check for file changes like this:

```
sftp.connect(config)
  .then(stats => {
    prevMtime = stats.mtime;
    setInterval(() => {
      sftp.stat(filePath)
        .then(stats => {
          if (stats.mtime.getTime() !== prevMtime.getTime()) {
            console.log(`File ${filePath} was modified`);
            prevMtime = stats.mtime;
          }
        })
    }, 5000);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the update, actually this part is working for me like i can read the files in the sftp server but i need to know how we can know whenever a new file is uploaded or not in the sftp server. Is that possible using this module?

Comment: @YethinS You can periodically check for file changes using `setInterval()` and `sftp.stat(filepath)`

Comment: I just executed the code and got like "Modified time : undefined", TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getT
ime')

Comment: @YethinS Well, that's completely another question. I suggest you ask another question providing your whole code. Also, check if you're reading a file/path that exists!